# Setup of Magento 2.1 with fails on file permission check

Tags: magento-2.1, php, installation, php-7

I created a Magento 2.1 project successfully in a Jailkit jail.  Running the html setup Readiness Check, the file permissions fail, because Magento is trying to use the root user's path, rather than the jail path.

```
"/var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/magento2/app/etc" - Not writable, change the permissions. Show details
"/var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/magento2/var" - Not writable, change the permissions. Show details
"/var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/magento2/pub/media" - Not writable, change the permissions. Show details
"/var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/magento2/pub/static" - Not writable, change the permissions. Show details
```

**(Actual path is: "/web/magento2/...")**

How can I set the actual Magento base path?

The command "pwd" responds with the correct path, "/web/magento2", but Magento is clearly looking at the ROOT user's path, rather than the jail's path.

I already tried setting permissions, and since we're in a jail, none of the jail users can use the full path either.

Comment: your path in jail is incorrect, looks like jail is not working at all, how can you see full path then??? magento installator must see only chroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access your **Magento root** folder and run this command below:

```
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

[Magento documentation reference.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html)

Comment: Thanks!  That corrected the issue.  I'll remember that in future.

Comment: this is nonsense, because his question was about path, not permissions... and his chroot path is wrong